# Why the dimension of span($x+x^3$) = 1 while that of span($x, x^3$) = 2

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

It is said that $\dim(\operatorname{span}(x+x^3)) = 1$ and $\dim(\operatorname{span}(x, x^3)) = 2$, but I don't understand why.
What is the basis of $\operatorname{span}(x+x^3)$ and $\operatorname{span}(x, x^3)$?

Comment: Their respective sets of generators are already bases. What you might be seeing is that $x+x^3\in span(x,x^3)$. But this means that $span(x+x^3)\subset span(x,x^3)$, which fit well with one having dimension 1 and the second dimension 2.

Comment: $x+x^3$ is _one_ vector. How could it span anything with higher dimension? On the other hand, $x$ and $x^3$ are two vectors, and if they are linearly independent ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "span" of the single polynomial $x^3+ x$ is all polynomials of the form $a(x^3+ x)$ where a can be any number.  That is of dimension "1" because every member of that space can be designated by single number "a".  The "span" of the two polynomials, $x^3$ and $x$, is all polynomials of the form $ax^3+ bx$.  That is of dimension "2" because two numbers, a and b, are required to designate a member of the space.

Note that $2x^3+ 3x$ is in the second space, the span of $x^3$ and $x$, but **not** in the first space.  The first space, the span of $x^3+ x$, is a one dimensional **subspace** of the second, two dimensional, space.